# ¿Cómo filtrar texto en un body de google docs para aplicar sugerencias de ortografía?

Tags: javascript

Quiero modificar un documento para siempre aplicar el texto sugerido cuando parece ser falso como en el siguiente ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo momento hice lo siguiente :

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = body.getText();
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    var words = text[i].editAsText();
    // aqui tengo que reemplacar el words si es falso et si hay un suggestion
    }
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: No queda para nada claro qué intentas conseguir, ¿que las palabras subrayadas en rojo se sustituyan por otras?

Comment: @dteterevkov sí exactamente. Lo siento, acabo de cambiar la imagen para ilustrar lo que estoy buscando.